# Conversion display wrong data

Tags: c#

If i take property as string that time output will properly come but i have to do it with date and time when i convert it with date and time it will show only one record with wrong date and time what should i do any Idea.
what i done in other case it working.But when i work with registry install date it's convert it into date and time but I don't get perfect date.

controllerModel.cs

```
private DateTime _installedOn;

public DateTime installedon
{
    get { return _installedOn; }
    set 
    { 
        _installedOn = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("installedon");
    }
}
```

ControlPanelViewModel.cs

```
#region Methods
public void ListedSoftware()
{
    string uninstallKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
    using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey))
    {
        foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
            {
                try
                {
                    Controller objct = new Controller();
                    objct.displayname = sk.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString();
                    objct.displayversion = sk.GetValue("DisplayVersion").ToString();
                    objct.publisher = sk.GetValue("Publisher").ToString();
                    objct.installedon = Convert.ToDateTime(sk.GetValue("InstallDate"));
                    objct.estimatedSize = sk.GetValue("EstimatedSize").ToString();
                    Students.Add(objct);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are having a hard time converting the value  in `InstallDate` to a `DataTime`?

Comment: when i pass string output like 20150122 with all installed software in registery , when i pass with datetime only get one data with wrong date like 01220001 what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in my registry, all of the `InstallDate` values seem to be in the format *yyyyMMdd*, where *yyyy* is the year, *MM* the month and *dd* the day.

To parse this string format into a `DateTime` object, you can use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method:

```
var timestampString = sk.GetValue("InstallDate").ToString();
var timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(timestampString, "yyyyMMdd",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Be aware that the `InstallDate` value may not exist in all subkeys in that part of the registry, so you will need to take that into account.

Comment: not working, Error like the best overloaded method match for 'system.dateTime.ParseExact()has some invalid argument i also try this "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff" but not working

Comment: That overload of `DateTime.ParseExact` (string,string,IFormatProvider) has existed in .NET since at least Framework 2.0, so I'm not sure why you're getting that error. Did you add `using System.Globalization;` at the top of your code file? You will need that namespace to reference `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: It's OK dude . I tried another way . if i get answer surely inform you Thank You. @Steven Rands

Comment: Sorry, just realised that the first line should have a ToString call on the end of it: `var timestampString = sk.GetValue("InstallDate").ToString();`. Try that. I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `DateTime.Parse()`, this one is work wor me.

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
objct.installedon = DateTime.Parse(sk.GetValue("InstallDate").ToString(), provider);
```

Btw, I got a similar result (01010001) when `sk.GetValue("InstallDate")` was null.

Comment: what value you got there - `sk.GetValue("InstallDate").ToString()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, Convert.ToDateTime(string) uses invalid format to parse your registry entry. You should experiment with your date format with [Convert.ToDateTime(String, IFormatProvider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9xk1h71t(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Here's good example on msdn with CultureInfo. Prehaps, [CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) will work for you